# How to avoid start/end points of line modification with ol.interaction.Modify

Tags: openlayers

To modify line geometry on OpenLayers(3-5), we use `ol.interaction.Modify`. What I want to do is, enable modify any points on line, except start / end points.

But just using `ol.interaction.Modify` normally, we can't prevent modifying start / end points. How to prevent it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible using more recent versions of OpenLayers.  This will work in version 4.6.5

```
  var pixelTolerance = 10;
  var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
    source: vector.getSource(),
    pixelTolerance: pixelTolerance,
    condition: function(e){
      var f = this.getMap().getFeaturesAtPixel(e.pixel,{
        hitTolerance: pixelTolerance,
        layerFilter: function(candidate) {
          return candidate === vector;
        }
      });
      if (f && f[0].getGeometry().getType() == 'LineString') {
        var coordinates = f[0].getGeometry().getCoordinates();
        var p0 = e.pixel;
        var p1 = this.getMap().getPixelFromCoordinate(coordinates[0]);
        var dx = p0[0]-p1[0];
        var dy = p0[1]-p1[1];
        if (Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy) <= pixelTolerance) {
          return false;
        }
        var p1 = this.getMap().getPixelFromCoordinate(coordinates.slice(-1)[0]);
        var dx = p0[0]-p1[0];
        var dy = p0[1]-p1[1];
        if (Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy) <= pixelTolerance) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try..